# Permute .txt file with Python

Tags: python, text, permutation

I have a 321MB txt file containing different books, I want to permute the file by selecting sections of 400 chars, permute the order of those sections and finally write them back.

The following block of code is my attempt at this, it results in an error.

```
import numpy as np

with open ('/home/gabriel/Desktop/GOD/Data/all_no_mix.txt','r') as fr:
    chunks = []
    char_len = 400
    data = fr.read()
    for i in range(0,len(data),400):
        chunks.append(data[i:char_len])
    fr.close()

with open ('/home/gabriel/Desktop/GOD/Data/all_mix.txt','a') as fw:
    num_chunks = len(chunks)
    order = np.random.permutation(num_chunks)
    for i in order:
        fw.write(chunks[i])
    fw.close()
```

It only writes the first 400 chars of the file `all_no_mix.txt` to `all_mix.txt`.

***What I am missing?***

Comment: `chunks.append(data[i:i+char_len])`

Comment: right now your chunk[0] is data[0:400], rest all chunks are 0 size due to data[800:400] etc

Comment: You are absolutely right, my bad....Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: @GGS By the way, you don't need those `close()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the reading loop you wrote:

> ```
>     chunks.append(data[i:char_len])
> ```

You want:

> ```
>     chunks.append(data[i:i+char_len])
> ```

---

Additionally, the final range argument [should be symbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)):

```
    for i in range(0, len(data), char_len):
```

---

Also [the docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html#quick-start) ask you to
avoid the [deprecated](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) calling sequence you used,
and to call `permutation` in this way:

```
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
        order = rng.permutation(num_chunks)
```